# Storing timezone in mysql date format

Tags: mysql, date

I want to store the current timezone in the mysql date datatype. For example,

```
10-Apr-2014 10:12:41 IST
```

What i want is: `DATE_FORMAT('10-Apr-2014 10:12:41 IST','%d-%b-%Y %H:%i:%S **timezone**')`

I searched the DATE_FORMAT and STR_TO_DATE formats but I didn't find any mention of the timezone.

Is there any way I will be able to do this?? I want the IST to appear at the end of date and time! Please help!

Comment: MySQL does not have any data type that can store time zone information.

Comment: Can u suggest a way i should proceed with for this? I need to store the date time info.

Comment: @FredoCorleone Use another column for the timezoneinfo.

Comment: I was looking for a dupe question but couldn't find any (as usual). You'll have to keep the TZ info in a separate column (possibly a FK to a master table).

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a dedicated data type for storing timezone information.

You have a choice of either:

1. Store timezone in a separate field (additional table column), the preferred way
2. Store the date, time and timezone as a VARCHAR, but this will make SQL queries based on date and time much harder and slower.